# Could Microsoft MakeCode be an alternative to the EV3 program?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, software

Is it possible to use [Microsoft MakeCode for the EV3](https://makecode.com/blog/lego/05-15-2018) as an alternative to the widely used EV3 program by LEGO? What are the benefits and drawbacks?

Comment: What is "good" is a matter of opinion. Perhaps you could define more specifically what you consider to be good or certain features you are looking for?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more objective and thus avoid getting it closed as opinion-based. If you feel this edit has changed the intention of hte question too much, feel free to either roll back or edit it further to better convey the original intent.

Comment: thanks for the feedback!